# ajax error checkUsn is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am doing login form connected to a mysql database and I want to check if username is existing inside database without reloading the whole page. I am using Ajax for sending and receiving data from the server. Now I'm stuck with this error can
"checkUsn is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup". can someone help me with this? i've tried to google it but it seems my code is correct. 
Here is my code

```
function checkUsn(){
    var usn = document.getElementById("usn").value;
    if(usn){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'checkdata.php',
            data: {
                emp_username: usn,
            },
            success: function(response){
                $('#status').html(response);
                if (response == "OK"){
                    return: true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('#status').html("INCORRECT USN AND PW");
        return false;
    }
}
```

checkdata.php

```
<?php
include 'db_config.php';
$conn = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

if(isset($_POST['emp_username'])){
    $usn = $_POST['emp_username'];

    $checkdata = "SELECT emp_username FROM emp_details where emp_username='$usn'";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $checkdata);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
        echo "OK";
    }else{
        echo "Your Username not exist";
    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

here is my form

```
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="/login_action.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkall();">
    <div class="container">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"></div>
      <img class="avatar img-responsive col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" src="img/employee_avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="usn"><b>Username</b></label>
      <input id="usn" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="usn" onkeyup="checkUsn();" required>

      <label for="pw"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pw" required>

      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="btnClickTest()"> test </button>
    <span id="status"> </span>
  </form>
```

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Functions used in inline javascript html attributes must be globally defined. Your function either isn't globally defined, or the file that defines it wasn't loaded.

Comment: Hi sir Patrick, how do I globally define that function?I tried some troubleshooting when ever I delete this line of code from ajax     
$('#status').html(response);
if (response == "OK"){
return: true;
}else{
return false;
}

the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I just got typo error on my code I write 
return: true;
instead of
return true;
now my code is now working smoothly.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to change you success function like this :


   success: function(response){
                $('#status').html(response);
                if (response == "succeed"){
                    return: true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
```